# Android : converting RGB888 to Y800

Tags: android, rgb, zbar

I am getting image captured from vuforia as RGB888 bytes[] . I want to pass this to zbar which is expecting the format to be Y800 .
How can i do that.

i tried

```
Image barcode = new Image(width, height, "RGB3");

    barcode.setData(imgRGB888);
    int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode.convert("Y800"));
```

but its not giving right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this Thread and Review Your Full Code :

http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/discussion/2308158/thread/ce0d36f8

By the Way : zbar Accepts ["GREY" format too](https://github.com/herbyme/zbar/blob/068c810f75994b61ab9edc689650d09a0fc78bf9/zbar/convert.c#L81)